# How does input impedance of oscilloscope affect circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, oscilloscope

I am taking circuits 1 lab and we are learning with oscilloscopes right now. Apparently the input impedance of the oscilloscope can affect my circuit. I am most specifically interested in how it affects the time constant of the circuit. How does the input impedance affect my circuit?
[image]

Comment: Let's see your circuit, the kind of signal you hope to measure, and please also tell us whether or not you are using a 1X, 10X, or 100X probe (or an active probe.) All probes have a complex impedance and there are various ways you can apply the probe to a circuit. So how all this affects a circuit depends a great deal upon the circuit, itself. But it also depends upon the scope bandwidth, signal, probe, probe fixture, etc. Would be nice if there were a simple answer that is always right no matter what. But that would be in a different universe. Not the one we live in.

Comment: Using a 1x probe. I added a picture of my circuit to the original question. So, input impedance doesn't have a general effect on a circuit? It depends on what it's connected to?

Comment: Thanks for adding the circuit. I'll +1, now. There's no information on the signal (supply), though. That's also a helpful piece to know. A 1X probe may have something like 50 pF and the input to the scope another 20 or 30 pF? The sum is perhaps getting close to 8% of C1, already. Also, the standard impedance of a scope is 1 MegOhm, which with a 1X probe means, well, the same or 1 MegOhm. Given the 2k Ohm resistor, R1, this probably isn't much of a problem (well under 0.5%.) You can reduce the load by using a 10X probe. But the capacitance, while less, may still affect what you read.

Comment: The signal frequency still matters, by the way. If the source is DC, then a little extra capacitance won't materially affect the reading as R1 is the key, then, and it will be the MegOhm resistance that dominates. But at high frequencies, the capacitance will be the dominant issue and that's when the probe capacitance will increasingly matter. Since the probe and scope capacitance is closer in magnitude to C1, this then becomes more important to you only at higher frequencies.

Comment: You can learn a little something about all this by setting this up in a Spice simulator. There are a number of them available for free, these days. But I use LTspice, myself. You can use a simulator to get a feel for the impact of a scope probe on a circuit by first setting up the ideal circuit itself (like the one you show) and then copying it and adding the "probe" impedance (a resistor and capacitor might be good enough, though you can always add other parasitics when you feel able to do that) and see how that impacts the result. By comparing the two circuit outputs you get an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to understand it, in my opinion, is to consider your oscilloscope as a load with a complex impedance (just like a resistor or a capacitor). Then you can apply all the rules you are learning or even simulate it in SPICE.

The impedance itself will vary from scope to scope but also from probe to probes. The 10x probes have a greater (better) input impedance then a 1x. On the other hand, they reduce the signal by a factor of 10. Meaning that you loose some resolution. Usually a 10x probe is a good balance of loading and resolution. An other aspect is the frequency. Naturally, the capacitance as a greater impact at higher frequencies. At low frequency, it is usually insignificant. (Usually: when the impedance of your circuit is significantly lower then the one of the oscilloscope)

In sensitive circuit, where the input impedance will be important, you need to use active probe. Active probe uses circuitry to allow a good input impedance while retaining the resolution of the oscilloscope.

When you are trying to measure the resonant frequency, the capacitance of the oscilloscope is often an issue. That being said, a quick way to check the impact of the oscilloscope is to place a first probe and measure the frequency. Then add a second one and it will change slightly. You can see with that technique the impact of your oscilloscope on the circuit!